# How to configure htaccess to work on subdirectory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony1

I have two website structure with 2 .htaccess like this:

```
www > html> .htaccess
www > vhosts > www.website2.com > http > .htaccess
```

both have this code inside

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

 # Reroute to index.php
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

This allows me to avoid putting index.php in URLs like:

http://localhost/website1.com/html/index.php/es_ES/hotels

can be used as:

http://localhost/website1.com/html/es_ES/hotels

but in the second website if I don't use index.php isn't working.

What's wrong?

Comment: You probably need to enable the interpretation of such dynamic configuration files. Take a look at the documentation of the `AllowOverride` command.

Comment: But apart from that: this looks like you have access to and control over the http servers host configuration. In that case: why do you use dynamic configuration files? You should place such rules in the real host configuration instead. If not for robustness reasons then at least for the sake of performance...